# How many inserts can e done per minute using only one Linux Java Process/One Thread?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have to insert 6 - 10 million rows fresh into a Postgresql Table. There is
no way out of these inserts.

I can scale by using multiple processes  running on multiple machines.

I would like to know Given a Intel i7 and 16GB memory Linux Machine,
What is the maximum number of rows  that can be inserted in 1 Minute using
only one Java Process?    Assuming TCP/IP tuning etc.

With this answer combined with my experiments, I can determine the number
of processes per machine and the number of machines.

I have hard time hitting more than 2000 - 2500 rows per minute.

I am using Hibernate 5.2.5 with Stateless Sessions and just one thread.

When I run 10 such processes, I am able to do 20,000 - 25000 inserts/minute
which is a linear increase in throughput.

I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong in my single process and 
whether the number is too low and How can I increase the per process
throughput, to say, at least 10000/minute.

thsnk,
Kumar

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I can easily insert 20.000 rows per second using Java

Comment: There are many thing that wants to slow down the performance: indexes, triggers, rules and so on. One of the way: `analise (explain, verbose, buffers) <your_qury>`.

Comment: Whenever I have to insert large numbers of records I skip hibernate and use raw jdbc and the `COPY` command.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is almost certainly to run all `INSERT`s in a single transaction (per thread).

Unless you do that, each `INSERT` runs in its own transaction, and that forces a flush to disk for the transaction log at the end of each insert, which will bring processing to a crawl.

If this is a one-time procedure, and you can live with the risk of losing your data (e.g., you made a good backup before you start), you can alternatively set `fsync=off` in PostgreSQL (but don't forget to reset it to its original value when you are done!).

Answer (score 1):

I used a lowest end Intel CPU HP Laptop.   One Process, One Thread:
I was able to get close to 50,000 inserts per minute (60 seconds) with no tuning etc.

***The original numbers were obtained in some other setup. I had my suspicions*** and hence I wanted to get answers from Stack Overflow.  I got my answer and hence no need for further answers.

Thank you for the one answer. These rules must also be followed. 
In addition, when a System is developed, it must be possible to do distributed and parallel programs.

thanks,
Kumar